# How to link WinInet using msys bash shell

Tags: c++, msys

I am having hard time figuring out how to link WinInet when compiling from bash shell in windows (msys)

'`Makefile`'

```
main:
    g++ -s -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -lwininet main.cpp -o main
```

'`main.cpp`'

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>



#define MAX  4096
#pragma comment (lib, "Wininet.lib")

void Request()
{
    HINTERNET hSession = InternetOpen("", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL,NULL,0);

}
int main()
{
    Request();
    return 0;
}
```

The error I got

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\tmp\cc1m5iEc.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xfa6): undefined reference to `__imp_InternetOpenA'
```

Things I tried :

- looked the path where `WinInet.lib` was and tried to use it with `-L` like so `g++ -L"path\\to\\WinInet.lib" main.cpp`
- changed `#pragma comment (lib, "Wininet.lib")` to `#pragma comment (lib, "WinInet.lib")`
- Tried using `-m64`
- Tried th `-L` method without `WinInet.lib`

How to properly link wininet from bash shell in msys

[MSYS](https://www.mingw-w64.org/) download link

Comment: GCC doesn't respect `#pragma comment (lib`, and normally doesn't use `.lib` files (it uses `.a`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your make file, you should move `-lwininet` after `main.cpp`

`g++ -s main.cpp -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -lwininet -Os -o main`